# ng2-map - Click producing two events

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I am using ng2-map for displaying google map in angular 2. I have used the click event to catch any clicks on the map. But it is producing two events on one click as given:

```
1) _.nk {latLng: _.F, pixel: _.z, ea: _.z, target: Ag}
2) MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 668, screenY: 278, clientX: 668, clientY: 158…}
```

What I need is the clicked point coordinates and I am getting it from the first result. But since two events are being produced, the click function works twice. Is there any method to stop the second event or stop the click function after the first event. Any help would be appreciated.
This is what I am using:

```
<ng2-map [zoom]="mapOptions.zoom" [minZoom]="mapOptions.minZoom" [center]="mapOptions.center" style="height:400px !important;" (click)="clickMap($event)"><ng2-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in clickMap():

```
clickMap(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
 .......
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But its giving stopPropagation is not a function error.

Comment: Could you log event : console.log(event) ?

Answer (score 0):

To respond to events that are triggered by the `google.maps.Map` use `mapClick` event instead of `click`, for example:

```
<ng2-map [zoom]="mapOptions.zoom" 
  [minZoom]="mapOptions.minZoom" 
  [center]="mapOptions.center"
  style="height:400px !important;"
  (mapClick)="clickMap($event)">
</ng2-map>
```

`ng2-map` emits `mapClick` event when *`google.maps.Map` gets clicked.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TqBzEX?p=preview)